# Возможно ли напрямую читать или записывать данные в ОЗУ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ассемблер, ram, информатика

Возможно ли реализовать чтение/запись данных прямиком в ОЗУ (по адресам?) в программе на Rust/Python/Ассебмлере(Aarch64) (в Linux).

Comment: Вы хотите реализовать работу с файлами в оперативной памяти?

Comment: А почему у вас возник такой вопрос?

Comment: [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1317946/edit) вопрос, напишите подробнее, какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Было просто интересно узнать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ваша программа будет запущена в обычной операционной системе, то скорее всего нет, так как ей будет предоставлена только [виртуальная память](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C).

Прямой доступ к ОЗУ имеет операционная система.